# issue with php namespace in "Laravel"

Tags: php, authentication, web, laravel

I use subfolder in the Controller 'folder',which works fine..
but when I write the blow code ..php return the error said "Auth is not found ,and the Input'

```
<?php
namespace website;


use Auth;
use Input;
use View;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('wcsite.index');
    }

    public function saveHome()
    {
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;
        $websiteData = Input::get('data');
        return $uid;
    }
}
```

but when I add 'use Auth,use Input',everything works fine...so ,anyone who can tell me ...is there any way to to this ,which "need not to use Auth,use Input in my subfolder Controllers'   Thank you a lot!

and my route is

```
Route::post('/wcsite',array('uses' => 'website\HomeController@saveHome'))->before('auth');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. You're saying that the code above is not working because PHP can't find the Auth and Input global class references but your code clearly shows you're importing them correctly.

PHP can't use the global Auth and Input class references without importing them first (which you're doing in the above code). It's going to assume they're located under the `website` namespace by default.

If you don't want to import hem with `use` statements you could always reference the global namespace by using a backslash before the class name like the code below:

```
<?php
namespace website;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return \View::make('wcsite.index');
    }

    public function saveHome()
    {
        $uid = \Auth::user()->id;
        $websiteData = \Input::get('data');

        return $uid;
    }
}
```

That being said, I prefer importing the classes first instead of using backslashes everywhere. It'll provide for much cleaner code.

Comment: yes.my code is working,my question is for "how to avoid wiriting use',哈哈:)